# websocket close on nitrous.io with different result

Tags: websocket, nitrousio

If I use my app(ios with c++ websocket code) with websocket connect nitrous.io, it will close connection if there is no signal.

Somebody has answered that this is nitrous.io feature,
but if I use web browser/html websocket connect to nitrous.io, it never closes the connection.

Confused by the different behavior.

(***web browser/html websocket connect to nitrous.io also closes after no signal for few hours)

Your comment welcome

Comment: Are the questions the exact same? If so, then this one will probably be closed as a duplicate, so could you explain why this one is different? Thanks!

Comment: not same, the former one the answer explained the reason of websocket connect break if it connected using c++ code from native app, but from web browser it never closes the connection, I hope to know the reason, if needed, I can paste my websocket.cpp code

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. You might want to remove the link to the other question, then- people will know that you asked it by clicking on your username.